# nginx mtls check client certificate

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

We are using like this to validate mTLS handshake

```
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/acme.crt
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/acme.key
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/acme-root-ca.pem
    ssl_verify_client optional;
```

Question mark -  we have some servers that have "latest" version and sends client certificate as part of traffic request and some servers have "old" version and doesnt send client certificate. With this scenario, how do we check that if no client certificate received at nginx, skip mTLS, if client certificate received at nginx, mTLS enforced..